How to dismiss keyboard from within toolbar?
The question is best described in code.
struct ContentView: View {
    enum FocusedField {
        case type1
        case type2
    }

    @State private var text: String = ""

    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?

    var body: some View {

        TextField("Type 1", text: $text)
            .focused($focusedField, equals: .type1)
        
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                TextField("Type 2", text: $text)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .type2)
                    .onSubmit {
                        focusedField = nil // This will switch to type1 instead of dismissing.
                    }
            }
        }

    }
}

The console will output:
-[RTIInputSystemClient remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input operation requires a valid sessionID. inputModality = Keyboard, inputOperation = <null selector>, customInfoType = UIEmojiSearchOperations

public func HideKeyboard() {
    #if canImport(UIKit)
    UIApplication.shared.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    #endif
}


This works, but doesn't play nice with SwiftUI which could lead to undesired effects. Thanks never the less.


I believe it is a bug in SwiftUI that is stopping focusedField = nil
from dismissing the keyboard and randomly selecting a different
textfield.

I created a work around view modifier .keyboard(_, equals:, isPresented:) that allows for the keyboard to be opened when isPresented is toggled.
This code does the following.

Present keyboard when keyboardIsPresented = true. This variable will automatically be true if a TextField is focused.
Detect when the keyboard is presented and immediately focus on the TextField in the keyboard-toolbar. This cannot be done with FocusState as it cannot focus on a TextField which does not exist yet. So the keyboard needs to be presented first in order for it to exist.
When we click on Return on the keyboard it will set keyboardIsPresented = false which will dismiss the keyboard.

Code
import SwiftUI
import Combine

struct ContentView: View {
    enum FocusedField {
        case keyboard
        case textField1
        case textField2
    }
    
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @FocusState private var focusedField: FocusedField?
    
    @State private var keyboardIsPresented: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        List {
            Button("Present Keyboard") {
                keyboardIsPresented = true
            }
            
            Button("Dismiss Keyboard") {
                keyboardIsPresented = false
            }
            
            Button("Switch Keyboard") {
                focusedField = .keyboard
            }
        
            Button("Erase Focused Field") {
                focusedField = nil
            }
            
            TextField("Textfield #1", text: $text)
                .focused($focusedField, equals: .textField1)
        }
        .toolbar {
            ToolbarItem(placement: .keyboard) {
                TextField("Textfield #2", text: $text)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: .textField2)
                    .onChange(of: focusedField, { oldValue, newValue in
                        if keyboardIsPresented && newValue == .keyboard {
                            focusedField = .textField2
                        }
                    })
                    .onSubmit {
                        keyboardIsPresented = false
                    }
            }
        }
        .keyboard($focusedField, equals: .keyboard, isPresented: $keyboardIsPresented)
    }
}

struct KeyboardViewModifier<Value>: ViewModifier where Value : Hashable {
    @FocusState.Binding var focusedField: Value?
    @State private var value: Value
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State private var text: String = ""
    @State private var shouldDismiss: Bool = false
    
    init(_ binding: FocusState<Value?>.Binding, equals value: Value, isPresented: Binding<Bool>) {
        self._focusedField = binding
        self.value = value
        self._isPresented = isPresented
    }
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(
                TextField("", text: $text)
                    .focused($focusedField, equals: value)
                    .opacity(0)
                    .frame(width: 0, height: 0)
                    .allowsHitTesting(false)
            )
            .onChange(of: isPresented) { oldValue, newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    if focusedField == value {
                        focusedField = nil
                    } else if focusedField != nil {
                        shouldDismiss = true
                        focusedField = value
                    }
                } else {
                    if focusedField == nil {
                        focusedField = value
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: focusedField) { oldValue, newValue in
                if shouldDismiss && newValue == value {
                    shouldDismiss = false
                    focusedField = nil
                    return
                }
                
                if !isPresented {
                    if newValue != nil {
                        isPresented = true
                    }
                } else {
                    if newValue == nil {
                        isPresented = false
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}

extension View {
    func keyboard<Value>(_ binding: FocusState<Value?>.Binding, equals value: Value, isPresented: Binding<Bool>) -> some View where Value : Hashable {
        modifier(KeyboardViewModifier(binding, equals: value, isPresented: isPresented))
    }
}

